# Scroll iframe by mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, html

It is possible to scroll an iframe by mouse coordinates on mouse move event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your trying to do is a drag scroll for a div.   Check this site out.
This is a demo to a Jquery Plugin that allows you to use mouse down events to drag your scroll area.  Simular to that of an Ipod touch or Iphone, but instead of a finger you use your mouse down

http://hitconsultants.com/dragscroll_scrollsync/scrollpane.html